# Finding an implicit from a type instance

Tags: scala, reflection, scala-2.10

Is it possible to use a *Type* instance as a normal Scala type? For example, in the following snippet, can one find *pi* by using *tpe*?

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

implicit val pi: Double = 3.14159265
val tpe = typeOf[Double]
implicitly[Double] // pi
implicitly[tpe]???
```

I'm afraid that there isn't an easy solution to achieve my goal, and that I am going to need a kind of factory to translate *tpe* into *implicitly[Double]*. Anyway, I think that integrating reflection types in Scala code could be really powerful, and so, not as crazy as it could seem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see how this would make much sense.

Let's just talk of what it sould mean for `implicitly`. It's supposed to fail to compile if there is no such implicit, or more than one eligeable.
But because the actual type represented by `tpe` is not known until runtime, making `implicitly` work with a type instance would make it impossible to emit any kind of compile error. The best you could do is to arrange for any call to `implicitly` to always compile, have the compiler store somewhere a list of all the implicit values in scope (for any type), and at runtime lookup in this list and throw an exception if none matches the type represented by `tpe` (or if there are several).
This could only make some kind of sense if we are talking about an alternate implementation of `implicitly`, say `dynamicImplicitly`.

Note that this would require the explicit support from the compiler (to capture all the implicits in scope at each call to `dynamicImplicitly`, which would thus not be a mere simple function), and be very inefficient in terms of space (how many implicits can be in scope at one given point? Yes, a lot, and they would all need to be referenced somehow in the bytecode at each call to `dynamicImplicitly`).

So my short answer is: don't hold your breath for this feature to be implemented anytime soon.
Technically it might be possible to implement `dynamicImplicitly` as a scala macro (provided that it is possible to get all the implicits in scope from scala macros, which I'm not even sure)

Comment: In the macro context, you have access to all the implicits in scope where the macro is going to be desplegated, using the `ctx.inferImplicit*` methods. I have used them in several macros, and they work really fine, but I didn't think in using that feature to solve this problem. Tomorrow I will give it a try, because it has a lot of sense. Thank you!